# Cannot with (de)serialize a List with polymorphic items in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an issue (de)serializing JSON that is not defined by me.

Here is some code and JSON that explains the issue:

Code:

```
public static class Base {
    public String klass = "base";
}

public static class SubBase extends Base {
}

public static class Sub1 extends SubBase {
    public Sub1() {
        klass = "Sub1";
    }
}

public static class Sub2 extends SubBase {
    public Sub2() {
        klass = "Sub2";
    }
}

public static class Holder {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY, property="type")
    @JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type (name = "sub1", value = Sub1.class),@JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "sub2", value = Sub2.class)})
    public List<Base> items = new ArrayList<Base>();
}


Holder holder = new Holder();
holder.items.add(new Sub1());
holder.items.add(new Sub1());

mapper.writeValueAsString(holder);
```

produces

```
{"items":[["sub1",{"klass":"Sub1"}],["sub1",{"klass":"Sub1"}]]}
```

If I change the JsonTypeInfo annotation to

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property="type")
```

produces

```
{"items":[{"sub1":{"klass":"Sub1"}},{"sub1":{"klass":"Sub1"}}]}
```

So far, all is good :)

However, the JSON I'm getting from the server has a slightly different structure:

```
{"type":"sub1", "items":[{"klass":"Sub1"},{"klass":"Sub1"}]}
```

Where the type of the items array is defined in the "type" property (note that all items in the "items" array are of the same class).
I just cannot figure out which JsonTypeInfo combination to use to make this happen. I tried setting the 'include' to ".EXTERNAL_PROPERTY", but this doesn't work.
Deserializing using this inclusion gives me "*Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value*" error message.

My question is: Which annotation do I need to use so that '*{"type":"sub1", "items":[{"klass":"Sub1"},{"klass":"Sub1"}]}*' will fill the 'items' array with all Sub1 instances based on the "*type*" property of the Holder?
If this is just not possible, is there another way to accomplish this (without the need of an custom serializer for Holder; a custom serializer just for the 'items' array would be fine)?

Thanks!

Comment: @localhost What kind of answer are you expecting? Why do you think the answer is outdated?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because it was asked in 2013, Jackson evolved a bit and maybe there is an answer to do it automatically.

Comment: @localhost I believe StaxMan is one of if not the developer of Jackson and they are active on Stack Overflow. You might want to post a comment on their answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis tyvm, i will ask him!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to map JSON you show automatically; it is not one of 4 types supported by Jackson.

If you can't make server produce more standard structure (for which automatic support exists), you will need to write a custom deserializer; or to do data-binding in two steps, first into an intermediate easily mappable structure (like `JsonNode` or `Map`) and then from that into desired structure manually extracting type, using that (for example, with `ObjectMapper.convertValue(object, resultType)`.

Comment: That's what I feared as well :)
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No problem, and sorry to be the harbinger of doom. :)

Comment: @StaxMan, could you please update an answer, if there is any solution available. Also, please look and this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638418/jsonsubtypes-list-of-polymorpic-objects-and-parcelable

Comment: @localhost not aware of any new solutions. There is unlimited amount of odd JSON, so this is unlikely to be supported without manual deserializers.