# How do I do polymorphic JSON deserialisation with Jackson based on attribute in parent class?

Tags: java, json, jackson

We have the following Json:

```
{
    "type" : "1",
    "otherStuff" : "2",
    ...
    "items" : [
        {
          "commonItemAttribute" : "value",
          "specificToType1" : "whatever"
          ...
        }
    ]
}
```

We need to polymorphically deserialise the items into different sub classes based on the type attribute.

Is it possible in a custom Jackson deserialiser to get the type value?

Can we safely look back up the Json tree using the JsonParser given to the deserialize method?

I found [this blog](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) about polymorphic deserialisation but it seems to require a type attribute on the items themselves.

Thanks

Comment: I think your question is similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605524/jackson-delay-deserializing-field/17625688 Maybe my answer for this question give you idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: This question might also be similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027628/cannot-with-deserialize-a-list-with-polymorphic-items-in-jackson

Answer (score 1):

This kind of JSON is not supported, since while "External" type ids of form:

{ "childType" : "SomeTypeId",
     "child" : { .... }
   }

are supported (with `@JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY`), they only work for simple types, not for `Collection`s or `Map`s.

So if you can't change JSON to be bit more standard (including type id for elements is the standard way), you will need to use custom serializers, deserializers.

Comment: How would I write a custom deserializer?If I create a custom one for the child objects you appear to only get the json for that child and have no way of looking back at the parent json to get the value of the type field.

Comment: I don't know -- all I am saying is that kind of JSON you are using is hard to map, and Jackson probably does not have functionality. So you will then either need to change processing (two-phase, first into a Tree, modify, then bind to POJO), handle with custom deserializer (for parent type, child won't work as you pointed out), or convince author of JSON model that it is cumbersome to use and should be changed.